# Actionbar Swipe Tabs deprecated

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, swipe

I'm developing an Android app (API >= 19). The app has an actionbar with a settings icon. I've implemented some sliding tabs with help of this tutorial:

http://www.feelzdroid.com/2014/10/android-action-bar-tabs-swipe-views.html

---

**But now, there are some problems:**

.

1. I got the following error

> You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this
>   activity

After inserting the following code to the activity in the Manifest, the error was solved but I don't know if that was the correct way?

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
```

---

2. Android Studio tells me that I'm using some deprecated functions like:

   public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.TabListener

or

```
Tab friendstab = getSupportActionBar().newTab().setText("Friends").setTabListener(this);
```

Should I solve this parts in my code? How can I do that?

---

3. With the solution of the tutorial my settings drop down of the actionbar does not work very well. If I click on the Settings Menu icon, the drop down appears not below the actionbar. It appears in the line of the action bar:

[image]

---

4. Is it possible do disable/hide the tabs of the action bar depending on a variable? For example: I click a button in settings and after returning from the settings, the tab menu is hidden or not